# ansible - how to put a simple role into a single file (at least for documentation)

Tags: ansible

I break my playbooks in roles which can be used for different setups. most of these roles are quite simple (few lines in tasks, perhaps a variable or a template).

I would prefer to have a role in a single file or at least print as a single file. The current distribution for roles into many files (not all are empty by default) makes documentation difficult.

I tried to insert a file `exampleRole.yml` with a single task (playbook-like) in `roles` but it is ignored when I execute the playbook with it without an error message.

```
--- 
tasks:
  - name: print to stdout
    action: command echo "hello"
```

How to write a role in a single file? Or at least a suggestion how to print a role in a single file for better documentation?

I like `ansible` and roles are helpful - but how to document them? To write good read-me files is not an option, as documentatin separated from code is always out-of-date!

Answer (score 3):

Q: **"*How to write a role in a single file?*"**

A: *ansible-playbook* does not check the structure of a role. A single task works fine. For example

```sh
shell> tree roles/minimal/
roles/minimal/
└── tasks
    └── main.yml

1 directory, 1 file
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/minimal/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Hello
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - minimal
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
   ...
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Hello
```

*ansible-playbook* will not complain if the role is an empty directory. There are other restrictions e.g. [ansible-galaxy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#sharing-roles-ansible-galaxy). As as hint, see [roles directory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections.html#roles-directory) inside collections.

Comment: Thank you for your example, which show - in my opinion - that roles DO check the structure but allow unused directories to be absent. It is still required to have under the name of the role a directory `tasks` and the file in it must be `main.yml`; deviation from these rules are ignored (without an error message!).  - What I hoped for is all the instructions for a role in a single file with the name of the role as a filename; this is not achieved (achievable) with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can't; Ansible requires that each role have the directory structure.

You can, however, write a task list in a single file (without subdirectories), then include it using [`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html). This can be done either in the playbook or within a role, letting you organise the tasks without setting up a whole new role.

You can also then apply a `when` clause to the `include_tasks` (rather than to each individual task), or use a Jinja substitution for the filename, like `include_tasks: "name_{{ ansible_facts.os_family | lower }}.yml"`

Comment: I tried your suggestions and they work but do not achieve a single file describing a role; I think it is unfortunate, that a compact representation for (relatively) simple roles is not feasible. Your suggestion amount to compose tasks from tasks (with include tasks) and not using roles. I will explore this style and see how far it gets me.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As far as I know, Ansible has nothing in between a task list and a full-blown role with all the directories. Probably the best approach will be a balance - a smaller number of roles, each of them with several task lists within it which include each other. Note that when you use a role, you can also specify the task list using the `tasks_from` option.

Comment: I had not paid attention to the option `tasks_from`; interesting, but likely confusing. It is unfortunate that ansible has no overall, rationally designed "programming language"; it is difficult to grasp how to use it in a structured way. I think it could be very useful to maintain smaller installations, but the learning curve is likely too steep. Your comments - as well as those of @vladimir botka - have clarified issues!